# Configuring multiple applications in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I would like to have multiple RoR applications that can communicate with each other (databases, method calls, ...).

Example of what I would like:

- a main application running on a URL http:// www.< application_name >.com
- a sub-application 1 running on a URL http:// www.< application1_name >.< application_name >.com
- a sub-application 2 running on a URL http:// www.< application2_name >.< application_name >.com

each with own databases.

How can I configure my applications? Where can I find a tutorial for my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Problem. In your case you will have 3 distinct Rails applications. You will setup your Webserver to send requests based on host accessed to one of the three applications. This is standard web server configuration. You'll need to read Apache or Nginx configuration on how to route request to the right rails application.

EDIT:

http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/3/11/ubuntu-intrepid-nginx-rails-and-mongrels
Not sure what you are going to use as your Web Server (Apache or Nginx or something else) or what you are going use as your application container (mongrel/passenger/thin etc) but this article above should help.

Comment: Do you know a tutorial or resource to setup RoR and Webserver to send requests based on host accessed to one of the my applications?

Comment: @user502052 (OP): You are looking for VirtualHost configuration.

Comment: @swanand .. thats the word i wanted to use :) 'virtual host'.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at the eco_apps gem - https://github.com/idapted/eco_apps. I heard the developers give a talk about it at Rails Conf '10. Fascinating stuff, though I haven't had a chance to use it yet.